# Bounty awarded by Community, what happened?

Tags: support, bounty

I stumbled upon the following question
[When do you use brace expansion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6035/when-do-you-use-brace-expansion)

The second scoring answer got a bounty awarded by Community. How and why does such a thing happen? I did not see it before.

Comment: Maybe that's what happens if the offerer fails to award it?

Comment: @derobert Yep, that seems to be right. I once put a bounty on a question, without awarding it, because the upvoted answer didn't answer the question, but it was awarded anyhow, but with only half of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) states

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), > the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Apparently, then the bounty is awarded by Community, instead of by the user offering the bounty in the first place.

Comment: It also happens if the user who offered the bounty is later deleted, but in [this case](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/6035/revisions) it's the auto-award